# What is the point of the Jasper PageContext pool?

Tags: tomcat

The title pretty-much says it all.

The issue is that the jasper `PageContext` pool creates, by default, a pool of 8 `PageContext` items in the thread-local data of a web-container thread. If the `BodyContent` objects that get stored there are large, then this can result in substantial data which, along with the web-container threads, is long-enough lived to end up in the old generation of the Java heap, where the cost of scavaging it is much higher than in the eden space.

If, and only if, the thread-pool is sized such that thread creation/deletion is really rare, then the only issue is size of the resulting data. Nonetheless, what are the advantages of the pool in the first place?

Comment: This is an old question, but I just ran into this again and wasted some time with it. You can turn it off by setting the system prop org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.USE_POOL=false.